# Catalog Page - Replace Filter Dropdown by Simple Links

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, product-list, filter, toolbar

I wish to replace the drop-down (position, name, price) on the catalog page by simple links.

[www\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.html](http://www%5Capp%5Cdesign%5Cfrontend%5Cbase%5Cdefault%5Ctemplate%5Ccatalog%5Cproduct%5Clist%5Ctoolbar.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just  change
from

```
<div class="sort-by">
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
            <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
            <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                    <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_desc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_asc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

to

```
<div class="sort-by">
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
            <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>

                <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>" > <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?> ASC</a>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'desc') ?>" > <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>DESC</a>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>
```